# Replace W with A, X with B, Y with C, Z with D in a string

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace all occurrences of W, X, Y, Z with A, B, C, D respectively in a string.

I tried this crude way;

```
A = A.replaceAll("W", "A").replaceAll("X", "B").replaceAll("Y", "C").replaceAll("Z", "D");
```

I am asking this question to learn a better and efficient style.

Comment: Your code and your introduction sentence are not coherent. Are we talking W, X, Y, Z or P, K, H, T?

Comment: An alternative would be to use StringBuilder. Find each index of the letters to replace, and call StringBuilder#replace(int startIndex, int endIndex, String newValue) The startIndex is incluse, the endIndex is exclusive. Honestly I think what you've done is just fine.

Comment: My bad! Apologies @Tunaki

Comment: Does this question deserve a vote down?

Answer (score 0):

just use String.replace(char, char).
But if you want to loop just one the chars, instead of 4 times, you could
iterate each to replace in a index lookup.

Ex: (this is only for capital alphabet, and you would need a whole larger char[] for any ascii, and much worse for unicode). The if could be avoided if you filled the entire 64k of chars upfront (some static variable of course).

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(yourinput);
String transform = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVABCD"; //notice the tail ABCD
for(int i=0, n=text.length(); i<n; i++) {
    char c = text.charAt(i);
    if(c>='A' && c<='Z')
        sb.setCharAt(i, transform.chartAt(c-'A'));
}
return text.toString();
```